# Javascript Countdown Timer according to EST

Tags: javascript, php, countdowntimer

i am creating a countdown timer according to EST. The timer should restart exactly at 12:00 am EST daily. i got exactly what I required but i ran into a small problem.

When The seconds timer goes finishes a minute, i see the minute decreased and seconds turns to 60. for eg:

if the timer is 13:15:01, after 1 second It shows 13:14:60. What I require here is 13:15:00 and the very next second, 13:14:59. I hope I made it clear.

Here are my codes :

Index.html :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script>
    var root_path = "http://localhost/countdown/";
    function init(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: root_path + "server_time.php",
            beforeSend: function(aj_msg) {
                //$("#countdown").html('');
            },
            success: function(aj_msg){
                $("#countdown").html('');
                phpMsg = JSON.parse(aj_msg);
                var est = "<span>" + Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].hour) + " :</span> ";
                est += Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].minute) + " : " ;
                est += Math.abs(phpMsg['ServerTime'][0].second);
                $("#countdown").html(est);
            }
        })
    }

    setInterval(init, 1000)
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
</body>
```

Server_time.php :

```
 <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
    $currenttime = date('G:i:s:u');
    list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
    $output = '{"ServerTime": [';
    $hrs -= 24;
    $mins -= 60;
    $secs -= 60;
    $output .= '{ "hour":"' . $hrs . '" , "minute":"' . $mins . '", "second":"' . $secs . '"}'; 
    $output .=']}';

    echo $output;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seriously, you're calling an ajax call every second in order to make a countdown timer?  Why?  The local javascript can keep time just fine.  If you want to start it with a server-based time once, that could be useful in some circumstances, but after that, the client can count time just fine without any further help from the server.  Perhaps you don't know about the `Date()` object in javascript?

Comment: Actually, I am practicing Javascript by my own without any help. Everything here is working fine until but the last second. Could you show me how I can keep this simple?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PHP so it's not clear to me what data you're sending back from the ajax call so I can't really help with parsing it in JS.